# Trailing slash throws 404 even after nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx

https://example.com/products - works

https://example.com/products/ - Throws 404

If i add a nginx rule, then it just redirects /products to /products/ still throwing 404

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

Comment: What else are you expecting with this `rewrite` rule (besides your regex looks really weird)? If you want to redirect `https://example.com/products/` to `https://example.com/products`, you can try `rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 permanent`, but I think this would lead to many other problems with your site and you doing something you don't describe in your question in a really wrong way.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I want both the routes to work

Comment: As I said, try `rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 permanent;` instead. But if something else on your site goes wrong with this configuration, you'd better show your full nginx config, I think you are trying to do something in a wrong way, there's no need for such a rule for a well written configurations.